# Magento New Product Page not updating group price

Tags: magento-1.8, soap, block-cache, reindex

I'm updating group price for customer group using soap api. I can view the group pirce in detailed porduct page as well as in admin dashboard but not in new product page(home page).

After refresh the "Blocks HTML output" under cache Management & Reindex data(index management) manually, i can see the price.

Or "Manage Product -> Select Product -> Price Tab -> Press Save" without making any changes it appeared.

How can avoid this manual process each time ?

Comment: What happens if you disable cache ?

Comment: Nothing happens. Perform **Reindex data** then it shows.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply reindexing at save time, avoiding manual update of indexes.

In admin, `System` -> `Index Management`:

In `Actions` combobox, select: `Change Index Mode`.

And then in `Index mode` combobox, select: `Update on save`.

Click `Submit` and add prices and check if it works (you may have to reindex the price manually before this setup change).

Comment: Index mode was "Update on Save". https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7384181/images/magento_index_mgmnt.png
PS: I'm using SOAP to create & update product catalog.

Comment: So, you update a group price, all indexes show Ready, and the price doesn't show ? You said before that `Reindex data` solves it (if all indexes are Ready a `Reindex data` should do nothing).